# Python assign dictionary value in a constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, dictionary, constructor

Please look at the below code.

```
signal = {
    "id": "p752",
}

class Trigger:
    def __init__(self, signal):
        self.id = signal['id'],
        
        print(type(signal['id']))
        print(type(self.id))
    
    def get_trigger(self):
        print(self.id)


t1 = Trigger(signal)
t1.get_trigger()
```

The output I get is

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'tuple'>
('p752',)
```

I honestly don't know what is happening here. When I assign signal['id'] to 'id' inside the constructor why is changing to a tuple?

Comment: `self.id = signal['id'],` has a trailing comma, which makes that a tuple. This appears to be a typo, so I voted to close it as such.

Comment: `signal['id'],` is a tuple.  `signal['id']` (no comma) is not a tuple. So change `self.id = signal['id'],` to `self.id = signal['id']`

Comment: I feel so stupid. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.id = signal['id']
```

Trailing comma is to be removed so it is treated as a tuple

Comment: I feel so stupid. Thanks.